# Outlook 2011 doesn't show flagged messages

Tags: macos, ms-office

I have Outlook 2011 installed (owa access) if a flag an e-mail to follow up, it doesn't appear in the smart-folder `flagged mail`. I tried rebuilding the database, delete and recreate my account nothing works. The Filter in the Smart-Folder is set to `Follow Up Flag -> Not Completed` any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue, don't put your outlook user data folder into the privacy settings of spotlight. If you do that, you can't search outlook anymore...